# finding the difference in data between two tables

Tags: sql, pgadmin

So I have been trying to find the difference in data between two tables. In one of my tables (old data) I have roughly around 16,000 rows of data. In my new table I have around 18,000 rows of data. So I know there should be roughly around a 2,000 data difference. I am trying to find exactly what has either been added or deleted or edited in the new table. This is my current code I am using:

```
SELECT UPC, Name
FROM ITEMS_032818 AS ND
WHERE (NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT UPC, NAME
         FROM ITEMS AS OD
         WHERE ( UPC = ND.UPC) OR ( NAME = ND.NAME)));
```

UPC is another word for the SKU of the products and the NAME of course is the NAME of the products. When I run this it returns 2388 rows of data which isn't bad but I can still find the the data returned in both tables.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What I am trying to get out of this is what has been either added to my new table of items or deleted from my old data table. my new data table is my most current of updated items. I want to see what has been deleted from my old data or new products added to my new items list that weren't on my old.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  How about comparing where the values, say, for UPC/Name.  Assuming the pair is unique in each table:

```
select upc, name, sum(in_old) as in_old, sum(in_new) as in_new
from ((select upc, name, 1 as in_old, 0 as in_new
       from ITEMS_032818
      ) union all
      (select upc, name, 0, 1
       from items
      )
     ) un
group by upc, name
having sum(in_old) <> 1 or sum(in_new) <> 1;
```

If something has `in_new` as 0, then it has been deleted.  If it has `in_old` as 0, then it has been added.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- added --
select 'added' type, * from item n 
where not exists (select 1 from item_031818 o where o.upc = n.upc and o.name = n.name )
-- deleted ---
UNION ALL
select 'deleted',* from item_031818 o
where not exists ( select 1 from item n where n.upc = o.upc and n.name = o.name)
```

Not able to determine which records have been edited without the table structure (e.g. primary key) and the rules.